# How to use a calendar to choose dates on web page?

Tags: web-applications

I have an html page that contains startdate and enddate as user inputs. I need to let the user choose from a calendar for these inputs, instead of requiring the user to type the dates.  Can you suggest anything to help?

EDIT:

I have an HTML page:

```
StartDate: yyyy-mm-dd             EndDate: yyyy-mm-dd
```

Currenly these two fields are text fields.

I would like to implement this using calender control where user can select any date from the calender.

Comment: Any reason you've asked almost the same question 5 times now?

Answer (score 3):

Check this out - http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/29/javascript-date-chooser/

By the way, you ought to be more clear and specific in asking your question.

Answer (score 3):

I think once you start needing this kind of controls, you should move to using javascript libraries.

I recommend you jquery or YUI (you have more: prototype, mootools, etc...)

Concretely for the calendar control, you can use [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), they have a special js for this. Once you download YUI you can find it here: /yui/build/calendar-min.js and you have a very good example in the path: /yui/examples/calendar.

The method you use to create it is: new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("cal","calendario",  { LOCALE_WEEKDAYS:"1char",  START_WEEKDAY: 1, mindate:"1/1/2008"});

If you prefer jquery, you will find a calendar control here:

http://ui.jquery.com/repository/tags/latest/demos/functional/#ui.datepicker

Answer (score 0):

If you're on ASP.NET you could use this one; http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Ajax-Calendar.aspx

I work for Ra-Ajax BTW...